# Cross platform extension in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Suppose I am having perspective lets say "DemoPerspective" for all platform which contain number of viewRef out of that lets say "DemoView" is define in windows plugin and now i am trying to run "DemoPerspective" in linux its showing "DemoView" is not available as it is part of Windows plugin.Its giving an error org.eclipse.core.runtime - org.eclipse.ui  - Unable to find view with id:"id of that plugin"

Comment: any solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't define the Windows only view in the perspective definition.

Instead use the [org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_perspectiveExtension.htm) extension point to define the additional view in the Windows only plugin.

Comment: OK but if then it will create 2 same ID in common and windows.

Comment: Well what do you expect to happen if you reference a view that does not exist?

Comment: suppose i am having perspective lets say "DemoPerspective" for all platform which contain number of viewRef out of that lets say "DemoView" is define in windows plugin and now i am trying to run "DemoPerspective" in linux its showing "DemoView" is not available as it is part of Windows plugin

Comment: Yes and I am saying don't define DemoView in DemoPerspective. Add it using the perspective extension in the Windows plugin. On Linux the view will not exist and won't be referenced. On Windows it will exist and will be in the perspective.

Comment: then whether i need to define "DemoPerspective" again in window plugin?

Comment: No you just use the perspective extension to add to the existing perspective.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88782/discussion-between-avinash-jadhav-and-greg-449).